# React google maps api, Edit polygon is behaving Weird

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-hooks, react-google-maps-api

so im working on a feature that let's drawn on a map, save the polygons cordinations and then display them back, the user should have the possibility to edit those polygons and save them again,
the add part was easy,
thanks to React google map api package,
when it came to edit i found this code that i don't fully understead and i used it,
https://codesandbox.io/s/reactgooglemapsapi-editing-a-polygon-popr2?file=/src/index.js
at first everything was working fine untill a bug was introduced, some of  the polygons that are drawn and saved  will disapear when the onEdit function is called.
when i save this disappearing polygon, it saves with the coordinates of null

this my whole component, i tried to add comments for better reading

```
// react
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";

// react router
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// MUI
import { Box, TextField, Button, CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";

// google map
import GeoMap from "../components/GeoMap";
import { useLoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

// styles
import { useStylesContainers } from "../../../../styles/Containers__styles";
import { StyledLoaderContainer } from "../../../../styles/Customers__styles";
import { useStylesButtons } from "../../../../styles/Buttons__styles";
import { Container } from "../../../../styles/Ingredient__styles";
import { useStylesDelivery } from "../../../../styles/Delivery__styles";

// useForm
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

// graphql
import {
  AreaPayload,
  CreateAreaDto,
  GetAllAreasDocument,
  PolygonIput,
  useCreateAreaMutation,
  useGetAllAreasQuery,
  useUpdateAreaMutation,
} from "../../../../graphql/types";

// external
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import clsx from "clsx";

interface formData {
  name: string;
  nameAr: string;
}
const AddEditArea = () => {
  // react hooks
  const [polygonCord, setpolygonCord] = useState<
    PolygonIput["coordinates"] | []
  >([]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const param = useParams();

  // custom style hooks
  const DeliveryClasses = useStylesDelivery();
  const ButtonClasses = useStylesButtons();
  const ContainersClasses = useStylesContainers();
  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.React_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY!,
    libraries: ["drawing"],
  });

  // apollo custom hooks
  const { data: areasData, loading } = useGetAllAreasQuery({
    variables: {
      input: { page: 0, documentPerPage: 0, name: "", sortBy: "NAME_A_Z" },
    },
  });

  const areaToUpdate: AreaPayload | undefined =
    areasData?.getAllAreas.data.find((area) => area._id === param.id);

  const [updateArea, { loading: upLoading }] = useUpdateAreaMutation();
  const [createArea, { loading: crLoading }] = useCreateAreaMutation();

  // useFrom
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      nameAr: "",
    },
  });

  // set the polygon from the areaToUpdate variable to a state, to then manipulate it
  useEffect(() => {
    if (areaToUpdate) {
      console.log("useEffect is Run");
      setpolygonCord(areaToUpdate?.cordinates?.coordinates);
      reset({ name: areaToUpdate.name!, nameAr: areaToUpdate.areaName?.AR! });
    }
  }, [areaToUpdate, reset]);

  const loadingStates = [!loading, isLoaded].every((elem) => !!elem);

  const center = useMemo(() => ({ lat: 25.2975, lng: 51.5495 }), []);
  const { enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  // save polygon path on polygon complete
  const handlePolygonComplete = (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => {
    const polygonPaths = polygon.getPath().getArray();

    const coordinates: number[][] = polygonPaths.map(
      (latLng: google.maps.LatLng) => [latLng.lat(), latLng.lng()]
    );

    coordinates.push(coordinates[0]);
    setpolygonCord([coordinates]);
  };

  // Edit Polygon
  const polygonRef = useRef<null | google.maps.Polygon>(null);
  const listenersRef = useRef<google.maps.MapsEventListener[]>([]);

  const onEdit = useCallback(() => {
    if (polygonRef.current) {
      const nextPath = polygonRef.current
        .getPath()
        .getArray()
        .map((latLng: google.maps.LatLng) => {
          return [latLng.lat(), latLng.lng()];
        });
      setpolygonCord([nextPath]);
    }
  }, [setpolygonCord]);

  const onLoad = useCallback(
    (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => {
      polygonRef.current = polygon;
      const path = polygon.getPath();
      listenersRef.current.push(
        path.addListener("set_at", onEdit),
        path.addListener("insert_at", onEdit),
        path.addListener("remove_at", onEdit)
      );
    },
    [onEdit]
  );

  const onUnmount = useCallback(() => {
    listenersRef.current.forEach((lis) => lis.remove());
    polygonRef.current = null;
    console.log("Unmount");
  }, []);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<formData> = async (data): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const area: CreateAreaDto = {
        name: data.name,
        areaName: {
          AR: data.nameAr,
          EN: data.name,
        },
        cordinates: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: polygonCord!,
        },
      };

      if (areaToUpdate) {
        // if the url has an id (update mode) call the update mutation
        await updateArea({
          variables: {
            input: { id: areaToUpdate._id, ...area },
          },
          refetchQueries: [GetAllAreasDocument],
        });
        enqueueSnackbar("Area Updated Successfully", {
          variant: "success",
          anchorOrigin: { vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center" },
        });
        setTimeout(() => closeSnackbar(), 5000);
        navigate("/admin/area/list_areas");
      } else {
        // if the url dosen't have and id  (Create mode ) call the Create mutation

        await createArea({
          variables: {
            input: area,
          },
          refetchQueries: [GetAllAreasDocument],
        });
        enqueueSnackbar("Area Added Successfully", {
          variant: "success",
          anchorOrigin: { vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center" },
        });
        setTimeout(() => closeSnackbar(), 5000);
        navigate("/admin/area/list_areas");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      enqueueSnackbar("Something went wrong, ", {
        variant: "error",
        anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
      });
    }
  };

  console.log("areaToUpdate ", areaToUpdate);
  console.log("polygonCord ", polygonCord);

  if (!loadingStates)
    return (
      <StyledLoaderContainer>
        <CircularProgress size={40} color="secondary" />
      </StyledLoaderContainer>
    );

  return (
    <Container>
      <Box
        sx={{
          width: "80%",
          maxWidth: 1200,
          height: 400,
          border: "1px dashed grey",
          marginX: "auto",
          marginBottom: 6,
        }}
      >
        {!isLoaded && (
          <StyledLoaderContainer>
            <CircularProgress size={40} color="secondary" />
          </StyledLoaderContainer>
        )}
        {isLoaded && (
          <GeoMap
            polygonCord={polygonCord!}
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onEdit={onEdit}
            onUnmount={onUnmount}
            update={areaToUpdate}
            center={center}
            containerClass="map-container"
            zoom={12}
            areas={areasData?.getAllAreas.data!}
            onPolygonComplete={handlePolygonComplete}
          />
        )}
      </Box>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            alignItems: "end",
            width: "80%",
            maxWidth: 1200,
            marginX: "auto",
          }}
        >
          <Box
            width={"40%"}
            minWidth={400}
            display={"flex"}
            justifyContent={"space-between"}
          >
            <Box minWidth={170}>
              <p className={ContainersClasses.section__subtitle}>Area Name</p>
              <TextField
                {...register("name")}
                id="demo-helper-text-misaligned"
                placeholder="e.g Doha"
              />
            </Box>
            <Box minWidth={170}>
              <p className={ContainersClasses.section__subtitle}>
                Area Name (AR)
              </p>
              <TextField
                {...register("nameAr")}
                id="demo-helper-text-misaligned"
                placeholder="e.g الدوحة "
              />
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <Box
            sx={{
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              marginTop: "15px",
            }}
            className={clsx(DeliveryClasses.buttons__container)}
          >
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              size="large"
              className={clsx(ButtonClasses.button_cancel_form)}
              onClick={() => navigate("/admin/area/list_areas")}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              className={ButtonClasses.button_submit_form}
              type="submit"
              disabled={crLoading || upLoading}
            >
              {(crLoading || upLoading) && (
                <CircularProgress
                  size={20}
                  style={{ marginRight: 10, color: "white" }}
                />
              )}
              Save Area
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AddEditArea;
```

this the child component Geomap component

```
import { DrawingManager, GoogleMap, Polygon } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { AreaPayload } from "../../../../graphql/types";
import { forwardRef } from "react";
interface propTypes {
  containerClass: string;
  center: { lat: number; lng: number };
  zoom: number;
  areas: AreaPayload[];
  update?: AreaPayload;
  polygonCord: number[][][];
  onPolygonComplete: (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => void;
  onLoad: (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => void;
  onEdit: () => void;
  onUnmount: () => void;
}

const GeoMap = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      polygonCord,
      containerClass,
      center,
      zoom,
      areas,
      update,
      onEdit,
      onLoad,
      onUnmount,
      onPolygonComplete,
    }: propTypes,
    ref
  ) => {
    const polygonOptions = {
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      fillColor: "#ff0000",
      strokeColor: "#ff0000",
      strokeWeight: 2,
      draggable: true,
      editable: true,
    };

    const drawingManagerOptions = {
      polygonOptions: {
        ...polygonOptions,
        fillColor: "green",
        strokeColor: "green",
      },
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON],
      },
    };
    const geoCenter = useMemo(() => {
      return center;
    }, [center]);

    return (
      <GoogleMap
        zoom={zoom}
        center={geoCenter}
        mapContainerClassName={containerClass}
      >
        <DrawingManager
          options={drawingManagerOptions}
          onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
        />

        {areas &&
          areas.map((area) => {
            const isUpdate = update?._id === area._id;
            const path = isUpdate ? polygonCord : area.cordinates?.coordinates;
            return (
              area.cordinates?.coordinates && (
                <Polygon
                  onMouseUp={onEdit}
                  onDragEnd={onEdit}
                  onLoad={onLoad}
                  onUnmount={onUnmount}
                  key={area._id}
                  path={path![0]?.map((latLng) => {
                    return { lat: latLng[0], lng: latLng[1] };
                  })}
                  options={{
                    ...polygonOptions,
                    draggable: isUpdate ? true : false,
                    editable: isUpdate ? true : false,
                    fillColor: isUpdate ? "green" : "#ff0000",
                    strokeColor: isUpdate ? "green" : "#ff0000",
                    zIndex: isUpdate ? 100 : 0,
                  }}
                />
              )
            );
          })}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
);

export default GeoMap;
```

this is an example of a polygon edit ui:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chIfV.png)

and this is a broken polygon behavior
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0bLh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDlSv.png)

my guess is it is something related to refs behavior through the renders...
i tried basic debugging and found out that what happens is when i try editing a polygon, i.e. onEdit gets called, it sets the state to null.
meaning that polygonRef wa null or empty ...